# How to know which nameserver should I use?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, godaddy

I have a domain like this: mydomain.org.co and I want it to point to a virtual server I acquired with Godaddy (with this WW.XX.YY.ZZ).

The problem is that the current Administration Panel for my domain allows me to change **only** the DNS server names:

[image: Name servers]

So, how can I know the name server that will point to WW.XX.YY.ZZ. I have SSH access if that helps.

Comment: Do you own the domain through GoDaddy as well, or is it through some other registrar?

Comment: My domain it's on another registrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though you can manage your domain through GoDaddy's control panel, even if they aren't your registrar.  See [this](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4041) article.  It looks like you'll be able to just change the name servers to GoDaddy's, and then you can create A records for your domain to point to your virtual server.

Comment: Thank you so much... I have done that and it works nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change only your DNS servers, you must deploy a DNS and configure it accordingly to what you want.

You don't have the possibility to put a redirect or something else ?

Comment: No... I don't have any other possibility to put a redirect. Any idea?